# Why do I get this error (solving a system of equations)?

Tags: equation-solving

I use the following code

```
Solve[Subscript[P, 1] == 0.5 *Subscript[P, 2] && 
  Subscript[P, 2] == Subscript[P, 1] + 0.5* Subscript[P, 3] && 
  Subscript[P, 3] == 0.5 *Subscript[P, 2] + 0.5* Subscript[P, 4] && 
  Subscript[P, 4] == 0.5* Subscript[P, 3] && 
  Subscript[P, 5] == 0.5 *Subscript[P, 4] && 
  Subscript[P, 1] + Subscript[P, 2] + Subscript[P, 3] + Subscript[P, 
    4] + Subscript[P, 5] == 1, {Subscript[P, 1], Subscript[P, 2], 
  Subscript[P, 3], Subscript[P, 4], Subscript[P, 5]}]
```

I get the error:

> Solve::ivar: "0.5`(0.5` (0.5`(0.5` Plus[<<2>>]+0.5
>   `Subscript[<<2>>])+0.5` Subscript[P, 3])+0.5` Subscript[P, 3]) is not a
>   valid variable."

[image]

Comment: Please rewrite your code without subscripts so that it is easier to read, and make sure that the code you have can be copy/pasted into Mathematica (currently it cannot).

Comment: @bills I am not sure how I can rewrite it without subscripts. Also, I can copy and paste it into Mathematica?

Comment: @bills: `Subscript` code can be properly pasted into Mathematica by first pasting it in, and then hitting `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `N`, which properly formats all the subscripts. In this case, when I run it, I get `{}` and no error messages, which suggests that the system has no solutions. The fact that the OP gets error messages suggests that he has previously assigned some of the $P_i$ to a value and forgot about it. Assuming this is the case, I'm voting to close as an elementary syntax error.

Comment: Since there are 6 linear equations in 5 unknowns, one might suspect that the system has no solutions, and indeed, removing the last equation and `Rationalize`ing yields `Reduce[P1 == P2/2 && P2 == P1 + P3/2 && P3 == P2/2 + P4/2 && 
  P4 == P3/2 && P5 == P4/2, {P1, P2, P3, P4, P5}]` giving `P1 == 0 && P2 == 0 && P3 == 0 && P4 == 0 && P5 == 0`, which is inconsistent with `P1 + P2 + P3 + P4 + P5 == 1`. So it's likely the OP also has a math error somewhere, in addition to the syntax error.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus First of all, thank you for your help! It could indeed be that the system has no solutions, but still, then I don't understand why Mathematica gives me this error message. I have included a screenshot for you to see. Do you know what might cause this error?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus (as can be seen from the screenshot, I did not define any of the $P_i$'s before)

Comment: @awearawer: Quit the kernel and restart, and try again. You probably forgot about a definition (I've done similar things before). It should fix it. If not, ping me again.

Comment: Mathematica will give max recursion errors when there are not enough constraints for the number of variables since the algorithms are thrashing seeking to find the solution.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Thanks, that did the trick. I appreciate all your help. Question can be closed :).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  `Solve` is not using any deep recursion. That's coming from some circularity involving a prior definition of a variable in terms of itself.